# Small powerbank, li-ion cell charging voltage problem

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, powerbanks

While ordering a replacement for an 18650 cell from a small powerbank, I've overlooked an important property of the battery. The old, broken one had 4.35 charging voltage and this is what the internal charger delivers. The new one, however, has typical 4.2 V charging voltage.

Is there anything I can do with the charger board to reduce the output voltage? Or is there no way and I just need to find a proper li-ion cell (with 4.35 V)? I do not consider using the existing combination as a good idea.

Models:

Old one -> Samsung ICR18650 30B

New one -> Samsung INR18650 30Q

Thanks in advance for any pragmatic hints!

Comment: Can you please share a model (manufacturer...) of the old cell and the new one?

Comment: Thanks for spotting I missed that, I've added the missing info to the original post.

Comment: Modern Lithium batteries that can be charged to 4.35V have the word "Graphene" in the name.

Comment: Do you know the IC in the powerbank? Have you a circuit? 4.35V is liable to be fairly or very fatal for a 4.2V max cell. You MAY be able to change a resistor divider depending on IC used. There are fancy things you may be able to do using eg FETS to drop a controlled 0.15V in one direction BUT the effort is unlikely to be worthwhile.

Comment: Providing links to components greatly helps people answer questions.